# Add comment to the mysql partition while adding the new partition to the table

Tags: mysql-8.0

I am creating new partition of type "LIST COLUMNS" to the table in mysql.

I also need to add the comment to the partition as some identification.

Can someone tell me the mysql syntax that how can I do this?

Atul

Answer (score 0):

I found the syntax. It is not a big thing but even in documentation the syntax is not provided so struggled a bit on it.

Anyway the problem has been resolved and the syntax to add comment to the partition while creating is:

```
CONCAT('ALTER TABLE <tableName> ADD PARTITION (PARTITION  ',<partitionName>,' VALUES in ( ',<value>,' ) COMMENT = "',<anyComment>,'")');
```

This is just when you want to concat something. The plain syntax is:

```
ALTER TABLE <tableName> ADD PARTITION (PARTITION  <partitionName> VALUES in ( <value> ) COMMENT = "<anyComment>");
```